# WPF C#: Splitting a long string

Tags: c#, string, split

I have been thinking about this problem for a long time, but now I managed to request help from those who know. I have a code, that is supposed to read text from a big file (a couple of Gbs) line by line. Every line can be around 500Mb as it must be a video, converted to base64 connected with video name. Here I read current line and separate video name from its' content (start from else).

```
        string[] fileline = GetFileLine(resPath, currentRow).Split(); //Here split causes SystemOutOfMemory
        try
        {
            string base64 = fileline[0].Replace(specSymbol, ' ');
            try
            {
                if (!IsVideo(ref base64) && !IsGif(ref base64))
                {
                    ShowPrimary();
                    imgFile.Source = BytesToBitmap(Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
                }
                else
                    btnLoadFile.Background = readyColor;
                if (fileline.Length > 1)
                    return fileline[1].Replace(specSymbol, ' ');
            }
            catch (Exception ex3) { MessageBox.Show("Next(4):" + ex3.Message); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex2) { MessageBox.Show("Next(3):" + ex2.Message); }
```

So my question is: does the way to split long strings exist or I only have to store names in a separate file without splitting?

UPD1: I have wrote a method using an advice @canton7 gave me. I have tested it on really small files (around 100 symbols), where it works good, but I am testing it now on 25Mb file, and the speed of the reading is awful (like 10Mb in an hour), even though, the reading of really big files didn't make the program to crash, so I think I'm on the right way.
I still wonder if there is a better method. If you have some advice on the ready method improvement - please give it here.

```
static string ReadFirstHalfAfter(string path, int skips = 0)
{
    int skipsDone = 0;
    int ri = 0;
    char[] buffer = new char[1];
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)//while reader is not at the end of file
    {
        reader.Read(buffer, ri, 1);//reading one element from the current position
        if (skipsDone < skips)//line skips not enough
        {
            if (buffer[buffer.Length - 1] == '\n')//current symbol is line end 
            { 
                skipsDone++;//line skip counted
                continue;
            }
        }
        else//enough line skips
        {
            if (buffer[buffer.Length - 1] == ' ') break; //if line separator - stop
            ExpandArray(ref buffer); //adding one more free element
            ri++; //switching element to read next
        }
        if (ri % 10000 == 0) Console.Write('.');
    }
    return new string(buffer).Trim(' ');
}
```

Comment: Why not use a StreamReader? That way you can read each line character-by-character: first the file name (keep reading characters until you find whitespace), and then you can read individual characters and stream them through a FromBase64Transform, and write each resulting byte directly into another file (or a local variable)

Comment: @canton7 Thanks for the advice, I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: It might be worth sanitizing this question a bit so it's more concise - this is a good topic but there's a lot of extra fluff that distracts from the core question of "How do I split a long string in C# without running out of memory".

Comment: "The maximum size of a String object in memory is 2-GB, or about 1 billion characters." have you tired using Substring and IndexOf? I would not suggest reading in 1 char at a time for a file of that size but that is IMHO.

Comment: @Sorceri That's the idea, but I'm not sure it would be more optimized than just splitting in terms of memory. Anyway, I will try it and let you know, thanks.

Comment: @GeekProgrammer "The Split methods allocate memory for the returned array object and a String object for each array element. " is why you are running out of memory when you split the entire file.  If each file is on 1 line then you should be fine to read in the file 1 line at a time with your stream reader.

Comment: @Sorceri I have tried out your method with substring and indexof, it really was more optimized, but not so much. I have undrestood that multiliniar string represetation is much more optimized anyway, so I will use it from now on. Thank you for the advice given.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To separate string into 2 pieces you can use substring to save memory, but if you want more memory to be saved - there is only one way through writing the line parts in the different rows.